# Sending files made by `jar xf` to another directory

Tags: ruby, command-line, jar, buildr

I have a JAR with a bunch of configs. I'd like to send them to the correct directory without cd'ing there.

Something like `jar xf config.jar --MAGIC-PARAM PATH/TO/DIRECTORY`

Is there such a thing? If it helps, this will be called by a Buildr extension (Ruby).

Comment: Can you copy `config.jar` to the destination directory first and call `jar xf` on the copy?

Comment: If you do, it will still extract in your current working directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the API documentation: http://buildr.apache.org/rdoc/classes/Buildr/Unzip.html

```
  unzip(dir => zip_file).target.invoke
```

Answer (score 2):

Alex's answer is good. If there's some special magic that `jar xf` does that makes you prefer it to unzipping (I'm not aware of any), here's another option:

```
FileUtils.cd('PATH/TO/DIRECTORY') do
  system("jar xf '#{_('config.jar')'")
end
```

It does involve cd'ing, but when you use `cd` with a block, the original directory is restored after the block. You will need to use either an absolute path or a path relative to the directory you changed to; I'm using buildr's `_` method to get an absolute path for a project-relative file.

Comment: This is what I ended up going with in the end.